# How to replace hash anchor (octothorpe) from href link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help figuring the last bit of this out. I am trying to change a set of anchor elements in the form of `<a href='#some link'>` to be this form: `<a href='some_link.html'>`. I'm sure it's something small I'm overlooking...below is a link as an example. Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/TGxANAHEiiMx/Dh8JM/24/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're iterating all `<a>` elements, also the ones without an `href` attribute (i.e. the ones that have a `name` attribute instead). Use `a[href]` instead, which only selects `<a>` elements which actually have an `href` attribute to replace: http://jsfiddle.net/Dh8JM/25/.

```
$('a[href]').attr(...);
```

Comment: @TGxANAHEiiMx: Please tick the check next to the answer that helped you, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
$('a').each(
    function(){
        var h = this.href.substring(this.href.indexOf('#')+1);
        if (h == 'top_page'){
            return false;
        }
        else {
            this.href = h.replace(/ /g, '_') + '.html';
        }
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Dh8JM/26/).

The above will turn `a` elements from:

```
<a href='#Tax Services'>Tax Services</a>
```

Into:

```
<a href="#Tax_Services.html">Tax Services</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this help

```
 $("a[href='#top_page']").attr("href","some_link.html");
```

Comment: No, I am excluding any href links to #top_page. Thanks for your input tho!

Answer (score 0):

You're encountering an error where some of your `<a>` tags don't have an href attribute defined. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Dh8JM/27/) is a working fiddle.

```
$('a').attr('href', function(i, val) {
    // skip the undefined ones with val !== undefined
    if (val !== '#top_page' && val !== undefined) {
        return val.replace(/\#/, '').replace(/\s/g, '_') + '.html';
    }
});
```

Comment: but don't you think its simple to just replace the href using attr() than to use regex? I know you are correcting OP's code, but would like to know your thoughts.

Comment: @DG3 if you look at the OPs code, you can see that OP is trying to change each href element depending on the already set href value.